# $2^k 3^l$ factorial design

Tags: r, references, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I'm looking for a reference for a $2^k 3^l$ fractional factorial design. Do such things exist? I could use a D-optimal but would prefer a clean aliasing structure. Any tips on software also good. Use R.

Answer (score 0):

Some references you can start with:

[Construction of Confounding Plans for Mixed Factorial Designs (JSTOR)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2238126?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by David White and Robert A. Hultquist.

[Theory of minimum aberration blocked regular mixed factorial designs (ScienceDirect)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375803002635) by Mingyao Ai and Runchu Zhang.

[Indicator function and complex coding for mixed fractional factorial designs (ScienceDirect)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375807000638) by Giovanni Pistone and Maria-Piera Rogantin

Comment: Brilliant. That's a great help. I'll follow them up.